# Getting segmentation fault error C++

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ and trying to solve the problems in programming challenges. I'm stuck in solving the jolly jumper. To get to the point, my program runs but after I input the first line and get an output, a segmentation fault follows. Here is my code:

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <cmath>

  using namespace std;

  bool is_jolly(int *list, int cap, bool* container){
      int difference = 0;
      for(int i=0; i<cap-1; i++){
          difference = list[i] - list[i+1];
          if(abs(difference) < cap && abs(difference) >= 1 && container[difference] == false){
            container[difference] = true;
            continue;
          }
          else return false; 
      }
      return true;
  }

  int main(){
  int n;
  bool used[30001];
  while(cin >> n){

        int * num_list = new int[n];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
              cin >> num_list[i];
              used[i+1] = false;
        }
        if(is_jolly(num_list,n,used))
                cout << "Jolly" << endl;
        else    cout << "Not Jolly" << endl;

        delete[] num_list;
     }

    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Did you try to step into your code with a debugger?

Comment: Start using `std::vector` instead of raw arrays and you will see all your seg fault woes disappear!

Comment: You should read [this blog post](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert on how to debug small programs such as your, and apply the techniques described there.

Comment: why would you need to store 30001 `bool`s ?

Comment: `container[difference]` ... not using `abs` input `2 0 100000` will cause segfault

Comment: `used[i+1] = false` The old "fake 1-based array" trick.  Doomed for failure due to not realizing that you could be using the (uninitialized) value at index 0:  `container[difference] = true;`  What if `difference` is 0?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie While I agree it's a bad trick, `difference` is never 0.

Comment: +1 for [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @BartvanNierop - Yes you're right.  However if it were 0-based, then position 0 would indicate if there is any two consecutive input values that had no differences.  Also, the extra test in the `if(abs..` would not be necessary.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I did agree it's a bad thing to do. =]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about no aparrent attempt to debug at all.

Comment: @BartvanNierop thanks for the link this will help me a lot since i don't know much knowledge on debugging techniques.

Comment: thanks guys i appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 3):

if difference can be negative (e.g. on input `2 0 10000`) then `container[difference]` uses negative index (e.g. `container[-10000]`) and that will cause segfault

```
  for(int i=0; i<cap-1; i++){
      difference = list[i] - list[i+1];
      if(abs(difference) < cap && abs(difference) >= 1 && container[difference] == false){
```

rather use:

```
  for(int i=0; i<cap-1; i++){
      difference = abs(list[i] - list[i+1]);
      if(difference < cap && difference >= 1 && container[difference] == false) {
```

....if that is what you want (I don't know what is the purpose)

Comment: Once `difference` is positive, going by the code from the OP, that entire if() statement could be this: `if (difference < cap) {`  It does no harm in setting `container[difference]` to `true` if it's already `true`, and `container[0]` is perfectly valid (but not used).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: but there is that `else return false`